# Why does "dotnet test" fail on ubuntu LTS 14.04?

Tags: .net, testing, command-line-interface

Can anyone help me figure out how to setup unit tests using "dotnet" in ubuntu? Now that dnx and dnu were replaced by dotnet, I am running into issues.

I have a `project.json` file with the following contents:

```
{                                                         
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": false
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime": "1.0.1-beta-*",
    "xunit": "2.1.0-*",
    "xunit.runner.dnx": "2.1.0-*"
  },

  "commands": {
    "test": "xunit.runner.dnx"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnxcore50": { }
  }
}
```

I run into problems when I run this command:

```
dotnet test
```

And the following is spit out:

```
dotnet-test Error: 0 : System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll': The specified module could not be found.
 (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at Interop.mincore.FormatMessage(Int32 dwFlags, IntPtr lpSource_mustBeNull, UInt32 dwMessageId, Int32 dwLanguageId, StringBuilder lpBuffer, Int32 nSize, IntPtr[] arguments)
   at Interop.mincore.TryGetErrorMessage(Int32 errorCode, StringBuilder sb, String& errorMsg)
   at Interop.mincore.GetMessage(Int32 errorCode)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.ResolvePath(String filename)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.Command.Execute()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Test.Program.RunConsole(ProjectContext projectContext, CommandLineApplication app, String testRunner)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Test.Program.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Main>b__0()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, I found the reason after some google-fu and digging through the dotnet code (and issues via github).

Bottom line: the feature is not implemented yet and there is a different bug (apparently already fixed but not in the current distro) that attempts to pInvoke into a Windows DLL whenever trying to run a program from a path that cannot be found.

See for yourself here: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/407 (read the last few entries by @piotrpMSFT)

In the end it turns out that:

```
dotnet test
```

Will attempt to run the command "dotnet-test-" *if* a "testRunner" has not been specified in the project.json. However, if the project.json contains a testRunner like this:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": false
  },

  "testRunner": "xunit",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime": "1.0.1-beta-*",
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnxcore50": { }
  }
}
```

Then it will try to run the program `dotnet-test-xunit` (since the "testRunner" was set to "xunit") and pass the project DLL as an argument.

Come on Microsoft dudes, help me out so I can start writing C# NuGet packages with tests.